# Bootstrap: Get Row-span like behavior?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a grid layout where I want a menu on the right in desktop mode, but on the top in mobile. This works fine like this:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-push-8"><div id="menu"></div><div id="side-content"></div></div>
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-pull-4"><div id="main-content"></div></div>
    </div>
```

But, I'd like to add other content directly below the menu on the right in desktop mode and have it move below the main content on mobile.

In other words, I'd like it to end up looking like what this would do on mobile:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12"><div id="menu"></div></div>
        <div class="col-xs-12"><div id="main-content"></div></div>
        <div class="col-xs-12"><div id="side-content"></div></div>
    </div>
```

Is there any way to make it so I could have two cells on the right in desktop mode, but have one flow above the main content while the other flows below the main content on mobile?

Edit: Here's a picture of what I mean
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go with the link or below code also may be it can help you -

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b91n23Lz/59/)

HTML Code -

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 menuDiv">
      <div id="menu">
        <h1>menu</h1></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
      <div id="main-content">
        <h1>main</h1></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 sideDiv">
      <div id="side-content">
        <h1>side</h1></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS Code -

```
#menu{
  background-color:#60E877;
}

#main-content{
  background-color:#E86060;
}

#side-content{
  background-color:#685818;
}

@media(min-width:768px){
  .menuDiv, .sideDiv{
    float:right;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - this works! The only thing I've noticed is that the layout fails if main-content is shorter than menu, because then "side" stacks against menu under main. But, I think I can handle that somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will work--

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
          
  </head>

    <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-push-8 col-md-4 col-md-push-8 col-lg-4 col-lg-push-8" style="background-color: blue;"><div id="menu"><h1>menu</h1></div></div>
        <div class="col-sm-pull-8 col-md-pull-8 col-lg-pull-8"><div id="main-content" style="background-color: red;"><h1>main</h1></div></div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-push-8 col-md-4 col-md-push-8 col-lg-4 col-lg-push-8" style="background-color: green;">
      <div id="side-content"><h1>side</h1></div></div>
      
        
        
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Thanks - but won't this always show the side content on the bottom below the main content? I'd want the side to be right below the menu on mobile. So, the right side should have menu then side on mobile.

Comment: not getting how you want your page to look like...please try to add a image .